# Creating web service

Tags: java, eclipse, jax-ws

I need to create very simple web service by using Java that will run in Tomcat on my Ubuntu machine.

Service should have one method `setData(value)` and one callback `value calbackDataArrived()` that I hope to use in JSP.

What service libraries are available on the market today? What is common one?

Would you recommend any tutorial on creating web service in my Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to answer it vaguely.

You can find the complete tutorial with code in this site
https://spring.io/guides#getting-started-guides